# Pasar valores hidden de un formulario a ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

estoy tratando de pasar los valores de varios input a una función en ajax, pero esta no los recoge.

```html
<input type="hidden" name="rooms" value="<?php echo $room ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="destination" value="<?php echo $id_destination ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="hotel" value="<?php echo $id_hotel ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="codigo" value="<?php echo $id_codigo ?>">
```

```js
function enviarDatosEmpleado(){
    //recogemos los valores de los inputs
    email=document.cliente.email.value;
    idrooms=document.cliente.rooms.val;
    iddestination=document.cliente.destination.val;
    idhotel=document.cliente.hotel.val;
    idcodigo=document.cliente.codigo.val;
}
```

Y si cambio los `hidden` en los input por text, sí los recibe.

Comment: Si utilizas los name para obtener el valor sería `document.formName.elements['abcName'].value`

Comment: Hola @Jesus. ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! ¿Y cuál es la llamada por AJAX? Tengo la sensación de que no estamos llamando a los métodos de igual forma. Creo que deberías **[edit]** la pregunta agregando las partes relevantes del código. Por ejemplo, "*estoy tratando de pasar los valores de varios input a una función en ajax*" <-- ¿en dónde, cuál es el código de esto? Cuando examinás el código en el explorador, ¿qué valores muestran los inputs? ¿En qué momento se llama a la función `enviarDatosEmpleado()`?

Comment: Sobre lo que menciona Cig, en particular `.value` en vez de `.val`. Sin embargo, deberíamos poder ver la pregunta completa antes de contestarla.

Comment: Gracias por responder, ya resolví el problema. Lamento mucho la parte del codigo, soy nuevo aquí.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por un lado hay un error de sintaxis en como recuperas los valores de los hidden. Estas usando ".val" en lugar de ".value". Por otro, para descartar otros problemas te recomiendo referenciar elementos con ids/clases en lugar de por nombres.

```
<input type="hidden" name="rooms" id="rooms" value="<?php echo $room ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="destination" id="destination" value="<?php echo $id_destination ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="hotel" id="hotel" value="<?php echo $id_hotel ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="codigo" id="codigo" value="<?php echo $id_codigo ?>">

function enviarDatosEmpleado(){
    //recogemos los valores de los inputs
    email=document.cliente.email.value;
    idrooms=document.getElementById("rooms").value;
    iddestination=document.getElementById("destination").value;
    idhotel=document.getElementById("hotel").value;
    idcodigo=document.getElementById("codigo").value;
}
```

Comment: Gracias amigo, ya funcionó!

Comment: Me alegro de que haya funcionado, por favor, califica la respuesta como correcta.

Answer (score 0):

> Archivo.Html

```
<form name="tuform" onsubmit="insert_empleado(); return false" >
<input type="hidden" name="rooms" id="rooms" value="<?php echo $room ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="destination" id="destination" value="<?php echo $id_destination ?>">
 </form>
```

> Ajax.js

```
function objetoAjax(){
            var xmlhttp=false;
            try {
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {

            try {
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (E) {
                xmlhttp = false;
            }
        }
        if (!xmlhttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest!='undefined') {
              xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            return xmlhttp;
        }

        function insert_empleado(){
              rooms=document.tuform.rooms.value;
              destination=document.tuform.destination.value;
              ajax=objetoAjax();
              ajax.open("POST", "tuarchivo.php",true);
              ajax.onreadystatechange=function() {
                    if (ajax.readyState==4) {
                        swal("Dato Agregado", "Correcto", "success")
                    }
             }
                ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                ajax.send("rooms="+rooms+"&destination="+destination)
        }
```

> tuarchivo.php

```
<?php 
include("../php/conexion.php");
//posts
$rooms=$_POST['rooms'];
$destination=$_POST['destination'];
$orden=mysqli_query($conexion,"update tutabla set rooms="$rooms"where id='$id'");
?>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias :) ya pude resolverlo